# Unable to Execute Distributed Testing in JMeter 4.0

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I have applied all the instructions to execute the distributed Testing for JMeter.
But When I run as "Remote Start-XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
Then I am getting "Exception creating connection: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX; nested  exception is: java.io.IOException: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key".

Can anyone help me Why I am getting that exception?

Reference that I used: [LINK](http://setskill.com/jmeter/how-to-execute-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032425/jmeter-got-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect-error-doing/52033304#52033304) is how I solve the same problem as yours. Have a try, hope this can help:

> when answering the question `What is your first and last name?`, you'll have to reply with `rmi` which is a corresponding value with `server.rmi.ssl.keystore.alias` in `jmeter.propertise`. Remember do NOT enter any custom value if u have not changed the `server.rmi.ssl.keystore.alias` in `jmeter.propertise` when u are trying to create a keystore.

Answer (score 1):

Given you use [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) additionally you need to follow steps from [Setting Up SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) User Manual Chapter

---

Alternatively if you don't want secure RMI communication between master and slave(s) you can add the next line to *user.properties* file

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

or pass it via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

The change has to be done on all engines (master and all the slaves)

References:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)

Comment: jmeter -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true.      After this command, I am getting: An error occurred: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

Comment: You're trying to start JMeter GUI on a Linux/Unix system which doesn't have X server installed or enabled or configured. You need to [run your JMeter test in non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like `jmeter -Jserver.rmi.ssl.disable=true -n -t test.jmx -Rslave1,slave2,slave3 -l result.jtl`

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter 4.0 you need to generate a keystore that will be used in distributed testing.

Follow this tutorial instead:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html

Pay particular attention to:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl

Comment: because you key was not generated, show logs of the keystore creation

Comment: Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
 at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
 at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:146) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
 at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:56) ~[?:1.8.0_144]. Copied from log

Comment: I have tried this : ./create-rmi-keystore.sh and got this in last line := Copy the generated rmi_keystore.jks to jmeter/bin folder or reference it in property 'server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file'

Comment: what parameters did you enter when running "create-rmi-keystore.sh" , particularly what password ? did you change it ? if so you need to update settings

Comment: i put like name: rmi, state and so on and I put password as "changeit"