# jmeter - Got 'Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect' error doing distributed tests

Tags: distributed-testing

Searched all the questions related to `recover key`error, got no answer on my situation.
So, I just have several simple operations:

1. install jmeter 4.0 (on centos 7)
2. cd to the `bin` directory, run `./create-rmi-keystore.sh` and pressed `Enter` in each steps(entered a password `123654` at final step), and finally it gives me

   > Warning:
   >   The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore rmi_keystore.jks -destkeystore rmi_keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
   >   Copy the generated rmi_keystore.jks to jmeter/bin folder or reference it in property 'server.rmi.ssl.keystore.file'
3. so I run `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore rmi_keystore.jks -destkeystore rmi_keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12` and give a password `123654`
4. It gives me:

> Enter source keystore password:
>   keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Can anybody give a hand, Thanks advance:)

Answer (score 0):

solved by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729987/jmeter-4-cant-execute-jmeter-server-in-windows-7) , to answer the question `What is your first and last name?`, you'll have to reply with `rmi` which must be a corresponding value with `server.rmi.ssl.keystore.alias` in `jmeter.propertise`.